# Python recursive proxy

Tags: python, object, proxy

Hopefully this should explain what i'm trying to achieve

```
class A(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello"

a = A()
a.b = A()
a.b.c = A()
a.b.d = []
a.b.d.append(A())


p = Proxy(a)

print p.b
"b accessed"
<__main__.A object at 0xb73f3bec>

print p.b.c
"b accessed"
"c accessed"
<__main__.A object at 0xb73f3dec>

print p.b.d
"b accessed"
"d accessed"
[<__main__.A object at 0xb73f3bcc>]

print p.b.d[0]
"b accessed"
"d accessed"
<__main__.A object at 0xb73e766c>

print p.b.d[0].hello()
"b accessed"
"d accessed"
"hello called"
"hello"
```

Basically as far as I walk down a structure it keeps returning proxy objects. It would be best if it only created these proxy objects when the attribute is accessed for the first time and stored on the 'parent'. The goal of this is so that I can do some logic just before any method  is called on an (nested) object

I had a look at:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/
But it only does the first layer, and I couldn't see how to manipulate it to work as I need.

Answer (score 0):

use a global cache, and create a proxy factory method that first checks the global cache before creating new proxies.

Note that this solution does not store child proxy objects on the 'parent'. instead, it uses `id(obj)` trick to retrieve the object from cache whatever how deepest is.

```
NOT_FOUND = object()

# global proxy cache
_id2obj_dict = {}

def remember(oid, proxy):
    _id2obj_dict[oid] = proxy
    return oid

def id2obj(oid):
    print("accessing cahed object")
    return _id2obj_dict[oid]

class A(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello"

class Proxy(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, obj):
        ''' object factory '''
        oid = id(obj)
        if oid in _id2obj_dict:
            return id2obj(oid)
        proxy = cls()
        proxy.obj = obj
        remember(oid, proxy)
        return proxy
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        prop = getattr(self.obj, attr, NOT_FOUND)
        if prop is NOT_FOUND:
            raise AttributeError()
        print("{} accessed".format(attr))
        proxy = Proxy.create(prop)
        return proxy
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        prop = self.obj.__getitem__(index)
        proxy = Proxy.create(prop)
        return proxy
    def __call__(self):
        print("{} called".format(self.obj.__name__))
        return self.obj()



a = A()
a.b = A()
a.b.c = A()
a.b.d = []
a.b.d.append(A())


p = Proxy.create(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options to consider with recursive proxies, with different trade-offs:

1. Override the class

   Probably the best and easiest to implement option. Make a decorator that replaces the class with the proxy class. You can make the proxy a bit more intelligent so that the class behaves like normal until a proxy behavior flag gets set on the instance.

   For example:

   ```py
   @ProxyWhenFlag('__turn_on_proxy__')
   class A:
       def hello(self):
           print "hello"

   a = A()
   a.b = A()
   a.b.c = A()
   a.b.d = []
   a.b.d.append(A())
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   >>> a.b
   <__main__.A object at 0xb73f3bec>
   >>> a.__turn_on_proxy__ = True
   >>> a.b
   "b accessed"
   <__main__.A object at 0xb73f3bec>
   ```
2. Modify the instance

   You can intercept most attribute accesses for objects by overriding `__getattribute__`

   A simple method would be to make an `imprint` method for your proxy, which removes all other methods, and only allows access to the underlying object through proxy methods.

   **Note**: `__` base methods would have to be overridden separately (they aren't intercepted by `__getattribute__`). `Tuples`, objects with `__slots__` and data structures (`List`, `Dict`, `Set`, etc.) all are optimized, and `__getattribute__` won't work there either

   A more complicated method would be to flag the object as a proxy, and take care of the proxying by overriding `Object`, `Tuple`, `List`, `Dict`, `Set`, etc. to check for the flag. You can use the `forbiddenfruit` module to override builtin methods. Take special care with doing this. It's very non-trivial, and will impact your entire application's performance. It still might be worth it though if you're going to be proxying almost everything (program analysis / tracing / AOP framework, etc.)
3. Use a global cache

   Probably the most cost effective option, as MBarsi points out. However, if you wanted to inject a proxy into other code, you'd still need to get the other code using the proxy object.